# XCode ld: library not found for -lrealsense2.2.50.0 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c++, xcode, intel, point-cloud-library, realsense

Iam quite new to this community. Take me as a noob in software development ( Help would be appreciated )
Iam running intel based 16 inch mac. with MacOs Monterey 12.4 version and Xcode Version 13.4.1 (13F100)

Facing a problem with Xcode for C++ development, i will attach the screen shot with this. when building it shows that library not found for **ld: library not found for -lrealsense2.2.50.0 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)** it was showing the same with the [libfreenect2](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2) driver as well.
**Things i tried**

1. I tried changing the name of the driver according to the name asked and added it even though it did not work.
2. Tried deleting the files from the derived directories and restarting everything
3. Creating a new project.
4. Building my own binary files using the SDK from [link](https://lightbuzz.com/realsense-macos/).

and lot other stuff on google, it didnt work. but when i run a cmake build with the given examples it works amazingly fine. but not when i wanted to develope my own project using the same code.

**PLEASE DIRECT ME** MAY BE A COURSE TOWARDS LEARNING XCODE.. anything.
[This is the code iam running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHmTE.png)
[And this is the error am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzac0.png)

Comment: [Tutorial for C++](https://www.learncpp.com/) There a lot of bad ones out there, this one is reasonable.

Comment: Found it, it was because i was miss matching the libraries and directories of different version.